# PHP/MySQL Table with Hyperlinks

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I have 2 PHP forms. One displays a list of events and the other displays the results of each specific event. On the page with the list of events I would like it so that a hyperlink can be created to access each individual event's results.

For example, on the Events page I click on row 2's hyperlink which will then take me to the Results page that has the results for that specific event.

Any help would be appreciated as I am very, very new to PHP. If any extra details are needed, please feel free to ask.

Thanks.

Edit: Sorry I'll show you what the Events form looks like so far:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('clubresults') or die( "Unable to select database");
$sql = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(EventDate, '%d/%m/%y') as newdate FROM Events";
$result = mysql_query ($sql);
?>
<table border = 1>
<tr>
<th>Event ID</th>
th>Event Name</th>
<th>Event Date</th>
<th>Location</th>
</tr>
<?php
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "</td><td>" . $row['EventID'] . "</td><td>" . $row['EventName'] . "</td><td>" . $row['newdate'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Location'] . "</td><tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: What will the URL for a specific event look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need two scripts, but just one:

```
events.php?list
events.php?event=1234
```

in there you only need to check for things:

```
$db = new Database(); # simplified


/* show event details if requested */

if (isset($_GET['event']) {
    if ($event = $db->getEventByID($_GET['event'])) {
        printf('<h2>Event: %s</h2>', htmlspecialchars($event->title));
        # ...
    }
}

/* show the list if requested (or show it always, whatever pleases you) */

if (isset($_GET['list']) {
    echo '<table>';
    foreach($db->getEventList() as $event) {
        printf('<tr><td><a href="?event=%d">%s</a></td></tr>'
               , $event->ID, htmlspecialchars($event->title));
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

---

**Edit:** As I saw in your updated question, you should switch from those oldskool `mysql_*` functions to the class style I outlined in my example, because it is much simpler to use. Here is a code-example that is close to yours:

```
<?php
/**
 * My First PDO Databaseclass
 */
class Database extends PDO
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $host = 'localhost';
        $name = 'clubresults';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = NULL;

        parent::__construct("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$name", $user, $pass);
        $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        // $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    }

    public function getEvents()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(EventDate, '%d/%m/%y') as newdate FROM Events";
        return $this->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
    }

    public function getEventByID($id)
    {
        $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Events WHERE EventID = %d;", $id);
        return $this->query($sql)->fetchObject();
    }
}

$db = new Database();

?>
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <th>Event ID</th>
        th>Event Name</th>
        <th>Event Date</th>
        <th>Location</th>
    </tr>
<?php
foreach($db->getEvents() as $event)
{
     echo "</td><td>" . $event->EventID . "</td><td>" . $event->EventName . "</td><td>" . $event->newdate . "</td><td>" . $event->Location . "</td><tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you sure I dont need something like 
echo '<a href="page2.php?ID='.$row['ID'].'">View Details</a>';
on one page and 
$query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE ID=".intval($_REQUEST['ID']);
on the results
(This is something I've seen elsewhere online.)

Comment: you need to do that only if the filename differs. if the filename is the same, you can start with `?`.