# How to successfully rewrite old mysql-php code with deprecated mysql_* functions? Part II

Tags: php, mysql, database, deprecated

Continuing from this topic where we explained most problems with PDO [How to successfully rewrite old mysql-php code with deprecated mysql_* functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919277/how-to-successfully-rewrite-old-mysql-php-code-with-deprecated-mysql-functions/10920267#10920267) now about understanding prepared statements... So in order to get remove mysql_* strings there are some examples so my question for all and other users may this find helpfull which solution is the best ... so example of old "made up* code:

```
in config.php: 
$db = new dbConn('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'pass', 'people', 'login');
in login.php
$db->selectDb("login");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM account WHERE id='".$_session["id"]."' LIMIT 1");  
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

$_session["id"] is defined when login actually, so now we have several options to do so:

```
In config.php:
$db_people = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=people;charset=UTF-8', 'root', 'pass');
$db_login = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=login;charset=UTF-8', 'root', 'pass');

And in login.php 1):
$stmt = $db_login->prepare("SELECT * FROM account WHERE id=? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute(array($_session["id"]));
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Or this one is better when exclude query? Or the previous one is better?

```
And in login.php 2):    
$query = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE id=? LIMIT 1";
$parameters = array($_session["id"]);
$statement = $db_login->prepare($query);
$statement->execute($parameters);
$results = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And this login form:

```
  public function login($user, $password)
  {
    global $web, $db;    
    if (!empty($user) && !empty($password))
    {    
      $user = $web->esc($user);
      $password = $web->doHash($user, $password);

      $db->selectDb('login');
      $qw = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM account WHERE username='".$user."' AND pass_hash='".$password."'");

      if (mysql_num_rows($qw) > 0)      
      {    
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($qw); 
        $_session['name'] = $result['username'];
        $_session['id'] = $result['id'];  
        return true;          
      }
      else
        return false;        
    }
    else
      return false;
  }
```

Transfered into this form:

```
  public function login($user, $password)
  {
    global $web, $db_login;    
    if (!empty($user) && !empty($password))
    {    
      $user = $web->esc($user);
      $password = $web->doHash($user, $password);

      $stmt = $db_login->prepare("SELECT * FROM account WHERE username=? AND pass_hash=?");
      $stmt->execute(array($user, $password));
      $rows = $stmt->rowCount();

      if ($rows > 0)      
      {    
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        $_session['name'] = $result['username'];
        $_session['id'] = $result['id'];  
        return true;          
      }
      else
        return false;        
    }
    else
      return false;
  }
```

Is it ok or again do separate query or maybe do it in complete different way? Thank you all.

Also when there is multiple stmt should I use different name for it? For example I use stmt once and make a result1 after I do stmt second with result2 should I choose different name also for stmt variable or only result name is ok to be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so solution login.php 1) seems to be ok simple and no rush.
Also the login page seems to be working fine and therefore it should be according to every rules and ok :)