# How to use mysql_* functions without the MySQL extension?

Tags: php, mysql, deprecated

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), saying that you must not use the `mysql_*` functions. How can I then use functions like: `mysql_query()`, `mysql_connect()` or `mysql_real_escape_string()` without the MySQL extension(`mysql_*`)?

Can I do this without PDO, because [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919277/how-to-successfully-rewrite-old-mysql-php-code-with-deprecated-mysql-functions) ask the same, but with PDO

Comment: there is mysqli extension, http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: The whole point of that post is that you shouldn't be using these functions. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your question is answered in the post you referred to. There's an answer that describes all the different extensions that can be used to query MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is the following:
Utilize the mysqli API as opposed to the mysql API
https://www.php.net/mysqli

There is a bit of learning involved because the functions don't behave exactly the same, but it's for the better.

For example, instead of using mysql_connect() to get your connection you would use https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Additionally, please follow these steps to make sure you have access to mysqli and PDO, as it's going to vary based on how you installed php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php

So, in summary, what that post you've pointed out is saying is that functions starting with mysql_ are deprecated and to not use them anymore.